# space in parentheses in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

most of the time when I look at the jQuery documentation, I see that there is a space inside a parenthesis (before and after whatever is between the parentheses) like so:

```
$( elem ).attr( "checked" );
```

Like you can see above, there a space before and after `elem` in the first parentheses and same thing in the second one. I was wondering, is there a purpose of doing that? What is the point of that?

Thank you

Comment: spaces in selectors do matter. not in way you did it.

Comment: It is just used to increase readability !

Comment: It is only a question of style and preferences, it doesn't change the code

Comment: Ok, so that has nothing to do with performance or speed or anything, it's just for style

Comment: It's there purely to irritate me :p

Comment: I agree with @ToKen, It's for readability.

Comment: Here's some easy reading on the subject matter (3rd example FTW!) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style#Spaces

Answer (score 2):

It is just for readability issue.

```
$( elem ).attr( "checked" );
```

is same with

```
$( 
elem
 ).attr(
"checked" 
);
```

or

```
$(elem).attr("checked");
```

for many languages.

New line, space and tab characters can be used in programming languages. These kind of spaces are called as **white space**.

Avoid using spaces in quoted texts. For example:

```
<script>
    var var1 = "some text here";
    var var2 = " some text here ";

    if (var1 == var2)
    {
        alert("Same");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Different"); //this message comes up
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spaces around function arguments make no difference to the meaning of the code at all.

They are sometimes added by code authors to enhance readability.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the convention. Nothing more. You can clearly see the code and it helps you understand it faster cos it's easier to read it. It's up to you, what convention will you use.